# Is it possible to book train tickets online in Thailand?

Tags: trains, online-resources, bookings, thailand, train-stations

Can I book Thai railway tickets online?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4170/should-i-book-thailand-rail-tickets-online-pre-trip-or-at-the-station-when-i-a?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as of February 2017 [the official State Railway of Thailand (SRT) online booking system](https://www.thairailwayticket.com/eTSRT/default.aspx?language=1) is online again, after being suspended for about 4 years. Here you can book train tickets directly with the SRT and receive them as PDF's (that need to be printed prior to boarding the train).

Note that in my experience, actual arrival times of the sleeper trains are usually always at least an hour later than the scheduled arrival time, so keep that in mind when planning connecting transports etc.

Other ways to book train tickets:

**Directly at a train station**

Note that popular routes sell out, so booking ahead of time is recommended. It's possible to book up to 60 days ahead.

**Via phone**

+66 222 337 62, +66 222 477 88 or +66 222 503 00

**Via an agent**

There are many, but one that seems to be often recommended if you want to book online and *travel from Bangkok* is [12Go Asia](https://12go.asia/en/), since they have an office in conjunction to the Hua Lumpong train station in Bangkok. Note that booking via agents typically require that you pick up your tickets at the agent, which is the reason the above mentioned company is convenient (since you're going to the train station anyway, and can pick up your tickets at their office).

Comment: good to know.  I used the online service before they suspended it.  Do they still have a 3% service charge?

Comment: @JonGrah There seems to be a 30 baht fee per ticket at the moment.

Comment: before it was like 20 baht + 3% fee if you use debit card.  Do they let you pay at 7-eleven, ATM, or via online banking of certain banks?  `7-eleven payment would be a huge leap forward.`    And I do hope they keep this option open.  The only negative is that you must bring printout with you.  I don't believe they have "will call" tickets that you pick up at train station.  Some stations close their office after a certain time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In January 2017, I had to buy tickets at stations (or agents).  It might be true that as of Feb 2017, this has changed, but keep in mind that announced goals for such improvements are not always met.

Comment: There is of course no way to know how long the service will last this time, but it is indeed working at the moment. BTW, this might be better suited as a comment than an answer.