# What to do without underwear on a 4 day trip?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, clothing, hygiene, sport-equipment

Ok, this might be a ridiculous question/situation but it's my situation.

I'm at a football camp in boston until Friday, and I've realized I forgot to pack any underwear (I wear boxers), I have the one pair I came with. I'm going to be pretty active for these days, so far my current strategy is to go commando at night, and wear the boxers only when I'm exercising. I can't get any from people or a store, does anyone have any ideas/improvisation tactics?

Comment: It's quite a statement for technological advancement that you have mobile internet access from wherever you are, but can't obtain new underwear.

Comment: Yeah... That's Irony for ya...

Comment: Well.  There is always the ubiquitous Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=boxer+briefs&sprefix=briefs%2Caps%2C144

Comment: Go to one of your fellow campers and make them an offer they can't refuse.

Comment: Do you have to were boxer shorts while exercising? A lot of sport shorts are quite comfortable without any underwear.

Comment: You're in Boston and there are no shops to buy underwear? You cannot be serious

Comment: I get you're at a camp and your time is most likely very well controlled... but, really? No you time _at all_? Or there just aren't any stores at all within walking distance? Even a small convenience store might have some shorts (not underwear, but shorts) which you could wear out of uniform...

Comment: Sadly you're [a bit too early](http://uk.businessinsider.com/expect-your-amazon-deliveries-within-30-minutes-via-drones-next-year-2015-6?r=US) to use Amazon's emergency delivery.

Comment: I often wear the same underwear 2 weeks long. And no one ever said That i stinked. So don't worry

Comment: I would bet that if you talked to one of the coaches, they'd be willing to run to the store for you.

Comment: "I wear them front, I wear them back..." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKG_L-fDk8U #BigHero6

Comment: Money can solve many problems (though not ones involving words like 'inoperable', unfortunately). I bet the coaches or other organizers have folks around that can do a run for you, maybe even for free (plus the undies, of course) but it can't hurt to offer to reimburse for gas etc. Get your 'ducks' in a row and figure the size out and go asking, you shall find and be comfortable. I've taken my kid to plenty of baseball camps, and there are always such people around.

Comment: Why don't you just wear your [towel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/why-exactly-is-it-so-important-not-to-forget-my-towel-when-hitchhiking/3268#3268)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the infamous "flip them around" technique. Arguably you can use one pair of boxers for four days if you flip them inside out and front to back. Indeed boxers, and tighty-whities, have two degrees of freedom which produce four possible rotations. This doesn't really work with thongs due to the difference in surface area between front and back. Just for kicks [here's a thread on a running forum discussing underwear and exercising (man I hope they're all kidding!)](http://www.letsrun.com/forum/flat_read.php?thread=3479369&page=1).

For added comfort you should of course think of letting them dry as much as possible, or even washing them, since exercising in them inevitably means sweating in them. For completeness sake note that if you don't wash your sweaty boxers and rotate them four times you'll probably stink. A lot.

Comment: The mention of four days in the question did make me wonder if it was a deliberate set-up for this punchline.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Punchline? What are you taking about? I do this every day! :D

Comment: I hope this is a joke

Comment: This method fails because you can only keep clean cloth (with a VERY stretchy assumption that dirt cannot go through the cloth) touching your privates for two days, before you have to make the part that touched your junk touch your behind and vice versa. This answer is therefore not valid.

Comment: Your underwear has two sides.  Use them.  But from a sweat / skin oil perspective, they soak through pretty easily.

Comment: sorry but you can't flip this stuff front-to-back, the shape is totally different and since he's doing sport he'd quickly get an itchy red mark due to the pulling. 

Still, underwear is fine for 2 days, I'd try to wash after that. The fact that he sweats in it is bad.

Comment: This technique works great for skidmarks but doesn't have much effect on "soaked with sweat".

Comment: Also, **real** underpants have *six* orientations before you have to double up! d-;

Comment: There's the infamous six day underwear that has three leg holes.  The idea is rotate and flip.

Comment: @Calchas Why a joke? Dire times call for dire measures.

Comment: So far I've been going with this method, chafing is a bit of an issue, but... well live and learn in hell.

Comment: @DylanMcGrath Please please please try to wash your boxers at least after using them twice. For hygiene sake.

Comment: @JoErNanO Dire times? The OP is in Boston, not deep in the Congo. OP can get whatever he wants. There is no more an excuse for having no underwear than there is an excuse for turning up stark naked (which at least would smell less). Even if someone thinks "no one notices the smell" trust me, we do, and it is not pleasant

Comment: @Calchas It's a camp. They rarely allow minors unaccompanied trips away, and quite often something like a football camp won't even allow accompanied trips. If the OP is not a extrovert, he is likely not going to want to call attention to himself so that the requisite hazing from other attendees would occur. This _can very well be **dire times** to him_. How dare you put your own sensibilities on another, especially if you are an adult extrovert.

Answer (score 61):

Wash them in the sink before you sleep, let them dry as much as possible until the morning, if they are not dry by then, iron them a bit and they will be dry.

If you can't get a hold of an iron, put them in front of the A/C or the heater, do not block the airway totally, just let the air pass through the boxers and it will make them dry in no time.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. This is a solid feasible solution.

Comment: @DylanMcGrath Years ago I did it myself when I forgot to bring the right number of boxers once..

Comment: Do you *have* to sleep in the sink?

Comment: @GregHewgill yes. (just because I didn't get you actually)

Comment: Why do you have to let the sink dry as much as possible? Ironing a wet sink can be dangerous.

Comment: @GregHewgill I see what you did there ;) now fixed..

Comment: damn you native speakers... it is my third language :D

Comment: You can also just put the damp boxers on and let your body heat do the work.  (Amusingly, my phone wanted to say "booty heat").  Depending on the temperature and humidity, this may be more or less uncomfortable.

Comment: Hairdryers are also an option for drying small items/areas of clothing, if there are any available where you are.

Comment: "it is my third language" Thank you for writing near-perfectly in the language I know, rather than one of the thousands that I don't. I always feel incredibly lucky that so many people make so much effort to speak English, and slightly guilty that I make very little effort to reciprocate.

Comment: @Davidricherby You know, it's never late to start. ;-)

Comment: @phoog I think that's a bad idea.

I'd add to not get any bad idea about soap: don't use normal soap on them! They will itch like crazy if you do.

Comment: Another way to dry something in a hurry is to put it between two or more dry layers of towel and press firmly. This won't get the last bit so do it after washing and wringing but before leaving it for the heater or aircon. If you find the first time that despite your best efforts it does not dry enough then next day try the drying part without the washing part. (Oh and four days is *nothing* you big baby!)

Comment: @phoog: That depends on how damp they are, what the weather conditions are, what activity will be undertaken, how vigorous and long lasting that activity will be, and what material they are made from. If you're unlucky the result can be very uncomfortable chafing, which I've experienced many times as an international hitchhiker. The moral is if you forget to take enough pairs of undies, don't also forget to take talcum powder!

Comment: Just be careful where you leave them to dry. Knowing teenage boys, there is a strong chance your boxers would disappear, leaving you with nothing to wear.

Comment: @hippietrail absolutely.  The only time I've ever done this, the shorts were minimally damp, the weather for most of the day was very dry and cool (actually, an air-conditioned office), the activity was not vigorous at all (mostly sitting), and the shorts were woven cotton.  Had any of these factors been significantly different, I expect I might have had a less acceptable experience.

Comment: @DavidRicherby frankly, there is very little reason not to learn English from a young age. It will almost always be useful in Europe and the Americas. However, for a native speaker, what should you learn? Mandarin? Maybe, but don't feel any guilt.

Answer (score 22):

I'm assuming you're at the [2015 BC Football High School Camp (Session II)](http://abcsportscamps.com/bcfootball/info/18117) - (quick Google search). Funny they did not list underwear in the Things to Bring section. On this page it mentions a Camp Store. Talk to someone at the store to see if they can pick some up for you. If money is an issue, have them contact someone (parent) who can figure that part out. Also, you could contact someone using one of the many numbers or email provided in the Contact Information section. This goal of this approach is to get some new skivvies versus the sink and iron approach. Also, check around with some of the other players to see if they forgot stuff too. Having a list of things for several people may help.

Comment: they didn't list it because it's pretty obvious you will need underwear. ;)

Comment: I'm really impressed on your detective abilities, yeah the store doesn't have them. But I'll try the rest.

Comment: @sgroves Not true. I follow a checklist to pack my bag. If it is not on the packlist, I will forget it. But then, I use my own checklist.

Comment: Man, I miss BC. I got my degree from BC in 1996 - and I'm thousands of miles away these days.

Comment: @sgroves Pssh. I was second string offensive line. The _one game_ I knew I was going to have to start and play (due to injury), i forgot my shoes. Just saying. To this day ( and that was 34 years ago ) it remains my single most painfully embarrassing night of my childhood.

Answer (score 14):

Inspired by the same-day delivery answer, I remembered there's a service called "[Magic](http://getmagicnow.com/)" where you basically text them what you want and they quote a price:

> We have trained operators standing by 24/7 to answer every one of your requests. Send us a text message, and we'll get you what you want. We'll order what you need from the appropriate service (e.g. DoorDash, Instacart, Postmates, etc.), and deal with them so you just automatically get what you want, like magic...

and from the FAQ:

> **Q: What kinds of things can I use Magic for?**
>
> Anything you want. As long as it's not illegal. Seriously. Just try it.

It might be useful if you have no money or credit cards as someone else could do it for you.

I've no idea if they're any good, I've always wanted to try it when I'm in the states but never have. I'm mostly posting because I think it would be awesome to ask a random service to find and deliver you underwear.

Comment: Now I got to try it out.

Answer (score 8):

You're at football camp? Someone else brought extra underwear. Barter for them.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: It's a solution to the problem posed in the question, why should it be a comment?

Comment: I agree. It is a solution.

Comment: If someone else bought 4 pairs of underwear, as part of your barter offer to wash a pair for them so they only need 3.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a couple of shorts with different length with you, you can use the shortest pair as underwear. Or even better, use swimwear - at least that dries quicker after washing them.

There's also:
- Ask a friend
- Ask a teacher
- Ask a random stranger

Personally I'd just wash them, you might need to improvise with soap or shampoo. It's what I do on business trips: take 2-3 pairs and wash the most recently used pair every evening. As an added benefit this also means I don't have to wash a mountain of dirty clothes when I come back after 4 weeks of travel. Just make absolutely sure that socks are completely dry before wearing them.