# Drinking tap water in a country where it is unsafe - anything to do after that?

Tags: health, tips-and-tricks, tap-water

Yesterday I drunk tap water in Ho Chi Minh. I knew it is unsafe to drink it, but only after I gulped down a cup of water did I notice it was tap water. Since it is safe in my country, I just drunk it unconsciously...

I believe that it won't get you into anything serious in most chances. But in general, is there anything you should/could do after recognizing to gulp down tap water in a country where it is unsafe? For example should I change what to eat for a while or should I not eat anything, etc...?

Comment: Not sure is duplicate, but definitely related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-prevent-delhi-belly

Comment: I think your best bet is to wait for the symptoms, if any.

Comment: Probably a good idea to get a hold of appropriate medication for stomach discomfort and adequate supplies to [safely rehydrate yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=oral+rehydration+solution&oq=oral+rehy&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.1261j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If you don't get sick, then you have some unnecessary purchases. If you do, you'll be extremely thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent "Delhi Belly"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/how-to-prevent-delhi-belly)

Comment: I don't think this question is a dupliate as 1) this question is strictly limited to tap water, and 2) this question is focused on "after-the incident" while the linked question is mostly on "before-the-incident".

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can be done afterwards, other than watch for any effects of drinking contaminated water. You may experience immediate gastrointestinal and stomach illness, such as cramps, nausea. vomiting, diarrhea. Should you believe you've been exposed to diseases that are waterborne (e.g., dysentery, typhoid, cholera, Guinea worm, cryptosporidium, cylcosporiasis, giardiasis, hepatitis E), seek medical help.