# Is it safe to drink bubble tea in Hong Kong?

Tags: health, food-and-drink, hong-kong, tap-water

I love [bubble tea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_tea) and I've seen it many places for sale while walking through Hong Kong.

I've read mixed reviews on the safety of Hong Kong's tap water supply, and so I am wondering whether this is safe for a foreigner to drink, since it is neither (1) hot or (2) pre-packaged.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is it safe to drink tea / coffee in India?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/610/108) (The basic principles for safety are the same.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I drank bubble tea in Hong Kong practically every day when I was travelling there but never fell ill. (Love bubble tea!) The way bubble tea is packaged in machines that seals the drink in means it's usually sold in shops with fairly good standards of hygiene. Besides, while the drink itself is not hot, bubble tea is prepared using chilled tea - and the preparation of any kind of tea does involve a stage where water needs to be boiled. That should effectively kill germs, if any, that remain in water.

Comment: I'd imagine it's not an issue for bubble tea (since non-boiling methods take far longer) but I feel it should be pointed out that not *all* tea involves boiling water: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iced_tea#Sun_and_.22refrigerator.22_tea

Comment: Point of order: the ice cubes may or may not be as safe as the tea water—if the bubble tea is with ice.