# What is the problem with Indian water? Bugs or Chemicals

Tags: india, tap-water

I will be heading out to India soon and saw one of these on Amazon.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lifesaver-Systems-Limited-4000-Bottle/dp/B001EHF99A

Demonstration Video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6w4xo-SKiQU

This cool gadget filters out bugs and dirt from water sources, however it does not filter chemicals.

My question is it going to be useful to take with me, as I dont want to use it on taps in India if I am still going to get ill from chemicals in the water that is different to what I am used to.

What do you think?

Comment: related : http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/drinking-tap-water-in-india

Comment: Thanks @Dirty-flow , from that question though everyone seems to say its bugs only. Do you think it is safe to assume that there are no trace minerals in Indian water?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even though I do not recommend anyone to drink tap water in India and the 18 years of my life I was born and brought up in Delhi, I had no idea that you could drink tap water in other countries. Fortunately, I know much more now.

Tap water in India is certainly filtered and chlorinated and all the other things one would expect in any other country. It is not potable though If you drink it, you **will** be putting yourself at a risk and the **locals know this very well**.

At home, we have a Reverse Osmosis system which we use to filter out the water more and make it drinkable. Depending on the location where you (and I mean extremely specific, for instance water in East Delhi and water in South Delhi is of completely different taste and salt levels) plan to visit, your nifty gadget might be useful, but I won't trust it for providing drinking water.

Almost everywhere in Delhi, people refrain from drinking tap water, even after some additional small filtration. I have had some instances where I or many others have used such small gadgets to filter  out the water, but **drinking this on a daily basis is certainly at your own risk**.

Furthermore, even if this device can remove most of the unfiltered bacteria, it would certainly **not provide a pleasant taste** in most of Delhi at least. Water in Delhi for instance is quite salty and I would suggest sticking to mineral unless there is absolute necessity.

**Mineral water is super cheap in India.** A standard 1L bottle of mineral water will cost you about **Rs. 15 ($0.25)**.

Comment: +1 for: "I had no idea that you could drink tap water in other countries". This places info in proper context, like: "it never occurred to me that anyone would try such a crazy thing"

Answer (score 0):

Indian water from the taps is not recommended to drink directly - best option is to buy mineral water which is widely available and very cheap also. If you buy in bulk you would get a very good deal also.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Kerala, in the Southern States of India
I don't recommend you to drink tap water because it was purified and also chlorinated but the taste of purified water is not like a normal water.
Waters taste will be different in different places, one example is you can travel or live at sea shore areas then taste of water will be salty and if you travel in high range area (means hill top) it will just be like a normal water.
Mineral water is available in India in very cheap rate as aditya said that 0.2$ for 1 Lt bottle and also 20 Lt bottles available in just 2.5$. 
if you live in a particular place then local distributors available.

If you use tap water for drinking, please boil it at 100 degree Celsius, it's good good for your health.