# Is LifeStraw a silver bullet water purification solution for travelling in India?

Tags: india, health, gear, tap-water

[LifeStraw](http://lifestraw.com/) has a 0.2 micron filter. Since "most bacteria are 0.2 µm in diameter and 2-8 µm in length" ([source](http://classes.midlandstech.edu/carterp/courses/bio225/chap04/lecture2.htm)), is it safe to drink water from any source using LifeStraw without boiling? (India in particular) Or should I better use water purification tablets?

[image]

Comment: Bacteria aren't the only concern in contaminated water; viruses and chemical pollutants could be much smaller.  I don't know how much of an issue these are in India, though.  It might depend on what specific part of India you are talking about.  But this product certainly can't guarantee you safe water from "any source".

Comment: A LifeStraw should be a hail mary for emergency use only, using bottled water from reliable sources is preferable

Comment: @Fiksdal How do you know?

Comment: @AE I may be working for LifeStraw...

Comment: Just drink bottled water, coke, and fanta like everyone else :)

Comment: Buy a couple of bottles of water and then keep refilling them at your hotel from RO machine.Carry your water where ever you go.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**No**.

Physical filters using pores with 0.2 µm (microfiltration) cannot

- remove heavy metal contamination (lead, mercury). This is possible with
  ion exchangers, distillation and nanofilters (see below).
- remove viruses. Most of them are too small and will easily pass through
  the filter.
- remove substances like salt and magnesium which make the water undrinkable. It is possible with the same principle and is then called 
  reverse osmosis, but it needs filter sizes about 1 nm. Also possible
  is the use of ion exchangers.
- remove pollution with big particles. For that reason the filter does not work alone, but needs prefilters like charcoal which prepares the water for the microfiltration. Such units used by survivalists and the military have several components to make water drinkable.

This does not mean that the product is not working or is unsafe, it simply means that you cannot trust **any** source. Boiling is not able to remove heavy metals (in contrast, it increases the concentration) and some pathogens, but for the "normal" usage it is sufficient. Inform yourself about the problems you may face in your destination country (In India it is mainly [giardiasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giardiasis)).

The normal and quite cheap way in India and in other countries for getting water is always use packaged, unopened(!) bottled water. I for myself prefer Micropur (silver ions) for water preparation.

Comment: [Looks like](https://edc2.healthtap.com/ht-staging/user_answer/reference_image/2971/large/Giardiasis.jpeg?1386670317) LifeStraw is effective against giardiasis (too big to pass through the filter).

Answer (score 27):

To add to Thorsten's excellent and quite accurate answer:

No, it takes quite a lot more than that to create perfectly safe water. For example, here's my Indian water purification system. I know it's not feasible for travellers, but I'm including it to illustrate just how much is actually needed to get really pure water:
[image]

Some things to note about it:

- It needs **electricity** to *pump* water through a very fine membrane (and another, rougher one). This process is known as [reverse osmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis). It's the same technology that's used to create the vast majority of bottled water in India. It needs an electric pump because the holes in the membrane are so *tiny* that even viruses can't get through. This makes pumping harder, and also means that there's a significant amount of wastewater that doesn't make it through the membrane, but goes back out into the ground instead.
- It has an additional **ultra-violet** filter which kills any number of microorganisms that might have made it through the membrane somehow. This is for absolute *redundancy*.
- It removes all dangerous chemicals, metals, minerals, salts, etc. from the water as well. This is needed where I live, since there are plenty of unhealthy substances in the ground water. The water that goes in shows roughly 600 parts per million of dissolved solids. (I measure it myself with a meter.) The output has around 20. (My machine also adds some healthy minerals to the water.)
- I paid 13.000 INR for that machine, while the LifeStraw sells for [1100 INR on Indian Amazon.](http://www.amazon.in/Lifestraw-Personal-Portable-Water-Purifier/dp/B006QF3TW4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1474240771&sr=8-1&keywords=lifestraw)

Needless to say, much of this can not be accomplished by the LifeStraw.

Many parts of India have [severe problems](http://timesofindia.com/home/environment/pollution/Poison-in-Indias-groundwater-posing-national-health-crisis/articleshow/12956971.cms) with industrial waste draining into the ground water. In the area where I live, there's no sewage or drainage system. Much of the household **sewage** and wastewater (as well as industrial and agricultural waste) goes directly into the ground. That includes detergents, chemicals, pesticides, feaces, etc. from factories, farms and households.

In some areas, water comes from lakes and rivers, and [these are often polluted and contaminated as well.](http://timesofindia.com/home/environment/pollution/80-of-Indias-surface-water-may-be-polluted-report-by-international-body-says/articleshow/47848532.cms)

I use RO water for cooking too. So does any *halfway* decent restaurant. Such restaurants and households have their own RO machines.

### Use bottled water.

For short trips I [certainly recommend bottled water.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76319/41775)

Comment: Do you need to add any minerals to the pure water it produces to make it healthy for long-term consumption?  I know that this is done in places where the city water supply goes through reverse osmosis (typically when the only water source is the sea).

Comment: @Szabolcs Natural, healthy water (like that from clean rivers, etc.) contains a certain amount of healthy minerals. The World Health Organization [has stated](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/nutrientschap12.pdf) that it may be less than healthy to consume totally distilled water (like RO water, which is totally cleared of practically everything.) This is because it lacks natural, beneficial minerals. Therefore, the [largest bottled water manufacturers in India](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76319/41775) add some healthy minerals to the water. So does my machine.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please note that for short periods (like on holidays, etc.), even demineralized water is probably nothing to be worried about, as our bodies keep internal reservoirs of minerals and can probably do fine for a few weeks.

Comment: In fact, drinking distilled water while on a healthy diet is not dangerous as we get the required minerals from other sources. You could also drink distilled water while taking additional supplements with it.

Comment: @Vilmar Unfortunately, it might not be that simple. The [WHO paper](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/nutrientschap12.pdf) I referred to earlier has quite a long chapter on potential risks. Not all of them can be mitigated by taking pills or having a varied diet. It's too technical to get into here, and I'll readily admit that I don't fully understand the subject matter. But it's a much researched subject. I'm sure you could find some references for you statement as well.

Comment: @Fiksdal I don't think I can provide an authorative source off the shelf, I just remeber reading about it not so long ago. But even glancing over the provided article, the highest concern is an amout of minerals lost in distilled water, which should not be a problem if the elements are acquired from another source. The other risks in question include the water's interaction with the environment (like higher metal intake if the water is stored/run through pipes) etc. Interesting read nevertheless, and it also states that water research is usally based on its toxicity, not its mineral components

Comment: @Vilmar "When used for cooking, soft water was found to cause substantial losses of all essential
elements from food (vegetables, meat, cereals). Such losses may reach up to 60 % for magnesium
and calcium or even more for some other microelements (e.g., copper 66 %, manganese 70 %,
cobalt 86 %). In contrast, when hard water is used for cooking, the loss of these elements is much
lower, and in some cases, an even higher calcium content was reported in food as a result of
cooking" Again, it's complex, and the paper also says you *can* possibly counteract the effect with supplements.

Comment: @Vilmar: "which should not be a problem". Well, WHO tried to study whether or not it *does* make a difference, not whether or not it *should*. For example, one of the results mentioned in the article Fiksdal linked, is that calcium and magnesium are taken up better from water than from food with the same content. I have no idea whether it's true or not, but it's an example of how "shouldn't" doesn't necessarily translate into "doesn't".

Comment: Hi Fiksdal, what is your water filtration system? Either a name or a link would be useful. I'm interested. Thanks.

Comment: @Fiksdal Ok, thank you. Reading the reviews of water filters on Amazon India, including yours, makes depressing reading. Have you had a good experience with yours?

Comment: My home RO filter doesn't use electricity.  Is the water pressure at the tap not as high as we use in the states?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Why? Mine is fine, yeah.

Comment: @JDługosz There's only ground water here. We have to pump it up to a tank on the roof. Pressure in the taps then depends on how high overhead the tank is. BTW, are you sure your machine is an actual RO system and not a carbon filter or something like that?

Comment: Oh yes; it has a carbon pre-filter but features a RO membrane that passes 1/5 the water through the membrane and the rest makes it to the end of the spiral and contains all the impurities now more concentrated.  The city water tower is higher than any house.

Answer (score 10):

Thorsten has an excellent response re: the filtration failings of the lifestraw itself.

I would find sucking on the lifestraw for all drinking water tiring. When I visited rural China, I used a tiny, battery-operated UV based sterilization system. It would sterilize 500ml of water at a time, plenty for everyday use.  I also used the water to wash my own utensils as I didn't always trust the utensils provided at rural restaurants. I even "nuked" the bottled water when I didn't trust that the bottle hadn't been refilled.

One thing to consider, for example: how are you going to rinse your mouth after you brush your teeth if you only had a lifestraw. Many tourists have unthinkingly used faucet water by mistake!

There's also the problem that water is not the only source of contamination. You need to be very careful about the type of food you eat and how it was prepared, stored, and served to you.

---

Note that UV and chlorine/iodine systems don't remove chemical contaminants. Many people use an activated carbon filter in conjunction. Still, a carbon filter and UV sterilizer can fit in a large nalgene water bottle and operate on batteries without ac power, which is more can be said for reverse osmosis systems.

Comment: Local people may develop immunity to bacteria or viruses, but not to chemical contaminants. If the source of your water is the same the local people uses and they are not dropping dead like fleas, you should not worry about chemical contaminants unless you are going to stay in the area for a very long time.

Comment: Even trace amounts of many toxins such as lead, PFOAs, and mercury will bioaccumulate.  I'd rather not risk my long term health. Thanks.

Comment: @SJuan76 Just because people aren't "dropping dead like fleas" doesn't mean they aren't ingesting harmful substances from the water. Saying that you "shouldn't worry" is irresponsible, IMO. Why would you risk drinking water that may contain harmful contaminants when bottled water is cheap and readily available? "Ah, just a bit of mercury won't hurt."? No, thanks, I prefer *zero* over a little bit.

Comment: @Fiksdal if you are so worried about trace chemicals in the water you should not be there in the first place. Or do you think that the food in these areas is grown or cooked with a different water? And do not get me started of what chemicals you can get *from* bottled water. Yes, taking some precautions is advisable, but let's not just overblow it.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'm not talking about "trace" chemicals. Many parts of India have severe problem with industrial waste into the ground water. Where I live, there's no sewage or drainage system. All the household (and industrial) waste-water just goes straight into the ground. That includes all the detergents, chemicals, etc. from all businesses and households. And yes, I used RO water for cooking as well. So does any *halfway* decent restaurant. Restaurants and households have their own RO machines.

Comment: @SJuan76 What sort of chemicals are you talking about from bottled water? [Reputable brands](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76319/41775) are subject to stringent testing by their own routines as well as their millions of customers. PPM meters are readily available for INR 500 (I have one.) I have friends who have had various bottled water tested in professional laboratories.

Comment: @SJuan76: and what if the locals *are* dropping dead like flies? Life expectancy in India is 13 years less than in the country I live. Obviously that's not solely or even mainly due to chemical contaminants in water, but it is *partly* due to that. So am I going to perform a sophisticated epidemiological study of each region I visit, or am I going to prefer RO water, just like the locals who can afford it do? I suppose if they're worried about the water they shouldn't live there either? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right. An RO system is one of the first thing most middle class families here buy once they can afford it. Pretty much only the poor people who have little or no choice do otherwise. And yes, *of course* the water quality in India is adverse to the health of the local population.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you share a link to the product you used?  I visited this page because I had heard of the lifestraw -- and pretty much nothing else.

Comment: I had a steripen (https://www.steripen.com/) and on another trip a sterilizerbuilt into a water bottle. I recommend the steripen - more flexible.

Comment: @SteveJessop Here is some confirmation of what you were talking about: http://timesofindia.com/home/environment/pollution/Poison-in-Indias-groundwater-posing-national-health-crisis/articleshow/12956971.cms

Comment: @SJuan76 Take a look at this article: http://timesofindia.com/home/environment/pollution/Poison-in-Indias-groundwater-posing-national-health-crisis/articleshow/12956971.cms