# Except pitcher filters, are there portable water filters needing electricity that filter chemicals, metals, and pathogens?

Tags: health, food-and-drink, gear

This question equals [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79496/13759); the only difference is that the filter can now be powered. Please specify:

4. the voltage of the filter. My relatives will be travelling only in North America, Western Europe, and Hong Kong.
5. whether a Voltage Converter can be used.
6. My relatives wish to avert Voltage Transformers because they are too heavy and inconvenient for travelling.

Comment: Will they often travel in areas where tap water is unsafe? Often filters which are not used right add danger rather than take it away, specially where the tap water is safe.

Comment: @Willeke No; they will access major cities, where the tap water is somewhat safe. But they will  travel to small cities, towns, national parks, and the hinterland, where the tap water is unsafe. I edited my linked question to add that they will always boil water.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're relying on a response to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79496/ and should first conduct research should that information be offered

Comment: how important is "chemicals and metals" in your decision process? Small battery operated UV filters do a great job on pathogens but not metals, and "chemicals" is far too broad to even answer.

Comment: also, boiling after filtering or UV treatment is at best pointless and at worst concentrating whatever you care about that the first treatment didn't remove - metals, chlorine, and so on are not removed by boiling.

Comment: For the vast majority of North America, Western Europe, and Hong Kong, it seems like they are likely to be in a place with safe and drinkable tap water, plentiful jugs of bottled water, or be in wilderness areas where a bulky plug-in RO filter is impractical.

Comment: Distillation works well for almost everything. || Reverse osmosis filters meet many needs. More anon maybe.

Comment: @ZachLipton They prefer additional filtration for more protection.

Comment: @KateGregory 1. Because they will always boil after filtration, am I correct that the boiling will kill the pathogens? Then we can prioritise chemicals and metals. 2. The boiling is intended to kill the pathogens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why not just use bottled water?

Anyway, I'll assume you have some reason not to.
Secondly, let me say that the solution I'm presenting here is probably far inferior to the one presented in the [answer to the other question of yours.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79526/41775) That one doesn't even need electricity, so it seems better by all standards.

Anyway, moving on, you can buy a [water distiller.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distillation)

[image]

When you boil water, steam rises from it. That steam will typically not contain any dangerous chemicals or pathogens. What a water distillation machine does is create such steam, and then collect it again as water in a vessel. Thus, you typically get perfectly pure water.

In the [other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79526/41775) I mentioned that in the long term, reverse osmosis systems are actually cheaper than buying bottled water for a long time. I'm guessing that this might not be the case for water distillers as they use a fair amount of electricity/energy to heat the water in order to distill it. This is in contrast to the RO option I referred to in the [answer to the other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79526/41775), which uses zero electricity/energy as it runs on the water pressure in the tap.)

Now, you mention that you need something you can use both on 110V and 240V electricity. This is a problem, because these devices don't typically transform the voltage, they usually just run straight on the current from the plug. Therefore, you'll typically find that they only support one type of voltage. So, if it's important to you to have a single device that you can use everywhere, I propose the following:

[image]

You can put this on top of any heat source, and it will give you distilled water. Of course, it does require you to have a heat source.

Again, this is very energy inefficient. It may be more convenient to consider the RO system from the other answer or, indeed, bottled water.

Since this isn't a shopping site, I won't link directly to any products. You can search any shopping site yourself for "water distiller" and you're good to go.

Comment: Distillation provides a pretty good Grail as well :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It turns out the RO system this answer was previously about actually doesn't need electricity so I had to repost it as a response to OPs [other question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79496/41775). I've edited this answer, and it **is** now about distillation. :)

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. Contaminants that have a lower boiling point than water (like say Methanol and Ethanol) will be in your condensed product too.

Comment: @CMaster That may be correct. Practically, though, do you think there is going to be methanol or ethanol in OPs tap water? I don't imagine it could possibly be present in significant quantities.

Comment: Just saying that it's not necessarily just water. I wouldn't expect many alcohols even in awful quality tap water though, no.

Comment: @CMaster Alright. I've reworded to correct the technical inaccuracies you pointed out.

Comment: @CMaster All statements are not necessarily true for values of all closely approaching unity :-). So, yes, distillation needs to be carried out with a modicum (or a soupcon) of intelligence. The normal method is to direct distillate to waste "initially". If the temperature of the boiling solution is monitored you would probably see an initial pause if significant amounts of low BP contaminant are present, but hopefully in most cases [tm] any such contamination would be relatively low level. For completeness - you can get Azeotropes ("constant boiling point" mixtures) which will not ...

Comment: ...  distill out contaminants below a certain level. An extreme example is Nitric acid which forms a CBP mixture with water at 68% and about 120 C. Hopefully there will not be much Nitric acid in any tapwater :-).